# Play store showing item not found on emulator

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my app on internal test and tried to download the app on android 10 emulator, but its showing error that item not found. I also tried to download the app on the real device but got the same error. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Give it some time. Google is running some checks while updating it catalogue. Your application will be available after sometime

Comment: @EugeneOgongo Thanks for your response, Its been 2 weeks now that the app is on internal test.

Comment: Have you tried sharing the opt ini url with your testers? Or You need to create a list of internal testers by email address. An internal test can have up to 100 testers per app.

Comment: I have added the emails of testers, and ask them to enrol using the link, Personally I also tried it on android 10 emulator but didn't work fo me as well.